# How to merge one-to-one and one-to-many input:output relationships in conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, though to be fair, I've learned a lot about Conduit, since previously I was mostly using canned examples with a few exceptions.

The basic problem is framed like this for conduits `A`, `B`, and `C`; `A .| B` (`A` feeds into `B`) and `A .| C`, and finally I need to have a function that takes B and C and produces an intermediate Conduit, call it `Merge B C`, so that I can do `(Merge B C) .| D`. My experience in non Haskell languages with FRP/streaming libraries suggest that there are several different ways to go about doing a "Merge" (e.g. the zip family of operations "sample on" - only produce new elements for `D` when one or more selected input conduits have a new value, etc).  I think my trouble is understanding how to do that in Conduit, if it is supported.

Even more specifically for my particular problem today, `B` has a 1:1 relationship with `A`, whereas `C` has a many:1 relationship with `A`, and ultimately in `D` I want repeated elements of `B` combined with the corresponding elements of `C`: if `a~b` and `a~c` for `a` in `A`, `b` in `B`, and `c` in `C`, then `(b,c)` are fed into `D`. So I was able to use `ZipSink` and the fact that it is actually a reasonable place to do a sink (performance aside, which I haven't looked at). Of course, as completely expected, `getZipSink` does not know anything about one to many relationships and how to deal with them; it has the widely defined behavior of zip to just cycle through input streams until  all input streams have been cycled through once.

I suppose one way to do this might be to somehow change my one-to-many stream into a one-to-one stream by doing a fold into something like a list. But then I'd have to unpack it later outside of the conduit context. At this point, I just want to ask to see what is the recommended way(s).

My actual code looks like (`A` is `sourceDirectoryDeep`, `B` is `processFileName`, `C` is `processCSV`, and `D` is (sort of, I suppose) `getZipSink`):

```
retrieveSmaXtec :: Path Abs Dir -> IO (Vector SxRecord)
retrieveSmaXtec sxDir = do
  rows <- sourceDirectoryDeep False (fromAbsDir sxDir)
    .| getZipSink (combine <$> ZipSink processFileName <*> ZipSink processCSV )
    & runConduitRes
  print rows
  rows & fmap fromRow & catMaybes & return
  where
    combine :: (Vector (MapRow Text)) -> (Vector (MapRow Text)) -> (Vector (MapRow Text))
    combine v1 v2 = (uncurry DM.union) <$> (zip v1 v2)
    processCSV :: (MonadResource m, MonadThrow m, PrimMonad m)=>
      ConduitT FilePath Void m (Vector ((MapRow Text)))
    processCSV = mapMC (liftIO . DTIO.readFile)
      .| intoCSV defCSVSettings
      .| sinkVector
    processFileName :: (MonadResource m, MonadThrow m, PrimMonad m) =>
      ConduitT FilePath Void m (Vector ((MapRow Text)))
    processFileName = mapC go
      .| sinkVector
      where
        go :: FilePath -> MapRow Text
        go fp = takeFileName fp
          & takeWhile (/= '.')
          & splitOn "_"
          & fmap Txt.pack
          & zip colNames
          & DM.fromList
        colNames = [markKey, idKey]
```

The imports (some of which may be extraneous) are:

```
import           Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators       as DCC
import           Data.CSV.Conduit
import           Data.Function                  ((&))
import           Data.List.Split                (splitOn)
import           Data.Map                       as DM
import           Data.Text                      (Text)
import qualified Data.Text                      as Txt
import qualified Data.Text.IO                   as DTIO
import           Data.Vector                    (Vector)
import           Path
import           System.FilePath.Posix
```

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-4.0.1/docs/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html#v:mergeConduits looks potentially useful but 1) I need to learn more about STM/channels, 2) it is deprecated and I don't see where it says why (**update**: apparently this is why: https://github.com/cgaebel/stm-conduit/issues/49), and 3) I still don't see where it is possible to define the behavior of *how* the merge happens, but maybe the implementation would be a good place to look for experimentation - but don't really have the time to create my own STM conduit API at the moment.

Comment: It seems Conduit is mainly made for non-forking (linear) pipelines, so I'm currently trying to split things up to this end ... still a WIP.

Comment: I found a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54369926/3096687 Not very stream-like, unsure if it is a good conduit-like solution, but it works.