# Why can one sometimes get "No instance for CSV Text Text arising from a use of `intoCSV`" when using csv-conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

My function is relatively simple and using fairly standard libraries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Foo where

import           Conduit
import           Data.CSV.Conduit

textToCSV :: Text -> Vector (MapRow Text)
textToCSV txt = replicateC 1 txt
  .| intoCSV defCSVSettings
  .| sinkVector & runConduitPure & runIdentity
```

I'd like to understand why I'm getting these type errors, and a solution would be great too:

```
    * No instance for (CSV Text (Vector (MapRow Text)))
        arising from a use of `intoCSV'
    * In the first argument of `(.|)', namely `intoCSV defCSVSettings'
      In the second argument of `(.|)', namely
        `intoCSV defCSVSettings .| sinkVector'
      In the first argument of `(&)', namely
        `replicateC 1 txt .| intoCSV defCSVSettings .| sinkVector'
    |
156 |   .| intoCSV defCSVSettings
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    * No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                         Identity (Vector (MapRow Text)))
        arising from a use of `sinkVector'
    * In the second argument of `(.|)', namely `sinkVector'
      In the second argument of `(.|)', namely
        `intoCSV defCSVSettings .| sinkVector'
      In the first argument of `(&)', namely
        `replicateC 1 txt .| intoCSV defCSVSettings .| sinkVector'
    |
157 |   .| sinkVector & runConduitPure & runIdentity
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Certainly, I can agree that an instance of `CSV Text Text` doesn't exist. But compared to what I'm doing, the typical usage using `sourceFile` seems to have a very [similar usage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-conduit). I'm just as confused about the second error regarding vectors.

**Possible workaround**:

Not really an answer to the question, but a workaround I found (that is also more succinct) was to replace my `textToCSV` function and several other auxiliary functions in the construction of my `processCSV` conduit:

```
processCSV :: (MonadResource m, MonadThrow m, PrimMonad m) =>
  ConduitT FilePath Void m (Vector (Vector (MapRow Text)))
processCSV = mapMC (readCSVFile defCSVSettings) .| sinkVector
```

Comment: Sorry for obvious question, but this isn't an operator precedence issue between .| and &, is it? From the formatting, it seems maybe the three & on the last line are meant to be groupped... put in parentheses?

Comment: Good question - I still don't trust myself remembering these things, so I usually check. I double checked just now, and indeed I do get the same errors using: `runIdentity $ runConduitPure $ replicateC`; there are only two & and I couldn't find a good way to group them using parentheses that didn't generate a more serious-looking type error, i.e. using `.| sinkVector & (runConduitPure & runIdentity)`.